# numpy array changes to string when writing to file

Tags: pandas, file, numpy, type-conversion

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is a numpy array:

```
 DF

      Name                     Vec
 0  Abenakiite-(Ce) [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.043, 0.0, 0.478, 0...
 1  Abernathyite    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
 2  Abhurite        [0.176, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.235, 0...
 3  Abswurmbachite  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0,...
```

When I check the data type of each element, the correct data type is returned.

```
 type(DF['Vec'].iloc[1])
 numpy.ndarray
```

I save this into a csv file:

```
DF.to_csv('.\\file.csv',sep='\t')
```

Now, when I read the file again,

```
new_DF=pd.read_csv('.\\file.csv',sep='\t')
```

and check the datatype of Vec at index 1:

```
type(new_DF['Vec'].iloc[1])   
str
```

The size of the numpy array is 1x127.

The data type has changed from a numpy array to a string. I can also see some new line elements in the individual vectors. I think this might be due to some problem when the vector is written into a csv but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: The information about data types is not saved into a CSV file. There is no way for Pandas CSV reader to know that what you attempt to read used to be a NumPy array in the past life. You should either save the array separately as a .npy file or transform the string back into an array yourself.

Comment: You should use `dtype` in `read_csv`. It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: What else do you expect.  csv is a text file?  The string format of an array, e.g. `'[0 1 2]'` is the only way it can write the 2nd column.  It can't write some sort of binary representation of the array (except maybe using `pickle.dumps`). Look at the `csv` file (with any text viewer).

Comment: I changed the read_csv command to:   
        new_DF=pd.read_csv('.\\file.csv',sep='\t',dtype={'Vec':np.ndarray})    However, the new error is : dtype <class 'numpy.ndarray'> not understood

Comment: `dtype` refers to the elements of an array, not the `type` of the array as a whole.  I don't think `read_csv` can handle this type of input.  It may be possible, though to process those strings after they are in the dataframe.

Comment: Are those arrays all the same length?  If so you might be able to extract that column to a `numpy`, concatenate the arrays (`vstack` or `stack`) to form one array, and then use the `np.savetxt` function to write a proper `csv` file for just the `vec` data.  It won't mix that with the `name` column.

Comment: The `dtype` of the original `vec` column is probably `object`.  It contains arrays, not strings or numbers.  In reload dataframe, the dtype might also be `object`, or maybe some `string` dtype.

Comment: Why are you storing NumPy arrays *within a series*? This is anti-pattern and is **guaranteed** to cause problems (portability, read/write performance, loss of vectorisation ability). You should split apart into multiple columns.

Comment: I am trying to use the vector as a feature for a ML model. If I split it into separate columns, the model will see it as as many features. I'm trying to see if the array (or vector) has an influence on the model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the comments I made a mistake and said `dtype` instead of `converters`. What you want is to convert them as you read them using a function. With some dummy variables:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['name1','name2'],'Vec':[np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]})
df.to_csv('tmp.csv')
def converter(instr):
    return np.fromstring(instr[1:-1],sep=' ')
df1=pd.read_csv('tmp.csv',converters={'Vec':converter})
df1.iloc[0,2]
array([1., 2.])
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally worked. What is the last line: df1.iloc[0,2]. It returns 'name1'

Comment: it was just to show that `Vec` column is converted to an array.

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at my very similar problem? I followed your answer but only received empty [] fields. Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960170/loading-a-csv-with-pandas-results-in-empty-fields-for-numpy-values-while-using-c

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works.
If you get empty lists, add the list slicing [1:-1] !

This converts the string
[-2.0797753, 3.6340227, -1.7011836]

to
-2.0797753, 3.6340227, -1.7011836

which is the required format for np.fromstring
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35450271)